# Cassandra - How to restore seed node from scratch?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I would like to know what is the best way to restore a dead seed node after wiping out all data from `/var/lib/cassandra/data` ?

Should I just restart the dead node as seed and all data from its primary ranges will be automatically streamed back to it ? Then, I will run a repair on it after it is up.

Or should I set a new node as seed then I restore my dead node with `auto_boostrap=true` ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

Comment: Yes, I've already seen the doc. However it's about how to replace a node by another one. In my case it's the same node (same IP adress). Should I set 'cassandra.replace_address' even if the IP adress is the same as the new node ? Thx

Comment: @fhuz same node, same IP should not matter at all, by EOD it's all C* nodes